# How to Start Dropbox After Installing It with Homebrew Cask?

Tags: macos, homebrew, dropbox, homebrew-cask

I just started using Homebrew and Cask today to install Unix and OS X applications on my Mac but I don't understand something about Cask.  When I run this command,

```
brew cask install dropbox
```

I can see that it installs it in /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/dropbox/latest/Dropbox.app and I can see that it has created a symlink ~/Applications/Dropbox.app that points to it, but when I look in Finder at my Applications folder, I don't see it there as I would if I had installed Dropbox from a .dmg file.  Also, I don't know how to start Dropbox from this symlink.  How do I get Cask to install OS X apps so that I can start them from either the Application folder or via the command line in a terminal session?

Comment: Are you looking in `/Applications` or `~/Applications`?

Comment: I'm clicking on Applications in the Finder Favorites which is in /Applications.  I would think Cask would create a link here since that's where other OS X apps get installed to.

Comment: I think it puts it in `~/Applications`. Check the `Applications` folder in your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

just run `open ~/Applications/Dropbox.app` from your cmd line.

See http://gillesfabio.github.io/homebrew-cask-homepage/ for overview.
Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

The behavior has changed over the last few months. If you update homebrew to version 1.0 and then run `brew cask install dropbox`, the application will now be physically moved into `/Applications/`, and the symlink will be created in `~/Applications/`.

Comment: This is only partially correct. With the new system, there are no symlinks created for apps.

Comment: For those who are using an older version of homebrew and want the same behaviour, you'll need to use `brew cask install <cask> --appdir="/Applications"`